# Log monitoring using Zabbix - Need help in configuring triggers

Tags: zabbix

I am monitoring logs of a **home-grown application** using **Zabbix** and I am using `logrt["/var/log/^application.log$","<regex-to-match-a-line-in-log-file>"]` items for it and also, I have triggers created for these items with `Multiple PROBLEM events generation` option enabled.

**Trigger expression:**

```
{Template_Application:logrt["/var/log/^application.log$","<regex-to-match-a-line-in-log-file>"].str("FATAL")}=1
```

The trigger is working as expected and Zabbix sends alerts for every instance of matched logged line.

**QUESTION:** There are instances when application has gone mad and generated lots of logs, which I have monitoring enabled for. I want Zabbix to work a bit more smart here, send alerts for first 10 log instances and keep quite for sometime(x minutes - can be static number) and then start monitoring the log file again.

Thanks.

Comment: [ZBXNEXT-2430](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2430) may potentially help here.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look.